# jquery submit form with enter issue

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, submit

I have a login form with jquery validation. I also use the following to detect if the user hit the enter button and to submit the form:

```
$('#login-form input').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        if ($('#login-form').validate().form()) {
            $('#login-form').submit();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

The issue I am having is that in my processing form I check if a `post` variable of `login` (a submit button) isset. If I submit the form via the aforementioned function the form doesn't get processed due to this reason. Is there a way for me to submit the form with jquery as if the user clicked the login button?

`<button type="submit" name="login" class="btn green pull-right">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger a button click

```
$('#login-form button[name="login"]').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to require the user to click the button to submit the form, then why check for the button press in the script that processes the form submission? Just check for the posting of one of the other form fields that is always submitted.

Comment: Have to give it to musa for correctly answering the question, but this is a good way of avoiding ambiguity. upvote